# Create a listing of every user which owns a file in a given directory as well as how many files and directories they own

Tags: linux, sed, ls, tail, cut

I am having trouble understanding the code : `ls -l /projects/ghosttrail | tail -n +2 | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | sort | uniq -c`. Can anybody give me a detailed explanation of what is happening at each step? I know I can do it myself by adding each command one by one but the code is not working for me and I fail to understand some things such as the meaning of +2 argument to tail or what did we achieve by putting the sed command and why are we not taking the 4th column in the cut command.

Source: https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php

Comment: How is the code "not working" for you?

Comment: not getting the desire output. only user on my machine is me. all files should be against my name. my name is spelled wrong and there is another user 1 which has 4 files @choroba

Comment: Try running the commands one by one and see where it breaks.

Comment: @choroba I mentioned that in the question and I have already done that. I don't see any use of the sed command over here. I don't under stand +2 to the tail and it should be 4 to cut

Comment: The reason the code is not working for you is that `\s` is non-standard. It works with GNU `sed`, but not with many other versions of `sed`. The portable version would be `sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g', which is a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Steps of the pipeline, output of previous command is used as input for the next one:

1. `ls -l /projects/ghosttrail` list directory contents (not beginning with dot) with details.
2. `tail -n +2` output starting with line 2 (removes the first line). Without `+`, [`tail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) would show last two lines (as many specified by `-n`, default 10).
3. `sed 's/\s\s*/ /g'` replaces multiple sequential spaces with a single one.
4. `cut -d ' ' -f 3` get the 3rd field (username).
5. `sort | uniq -c` sort and count unique lines. `sort` is used because `uniq` doesn't detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent as explained in [`man uniq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq).

Alternative way to get the same  results using GNU [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.*' -printf '%u\n' | sort | uniq
```

`find` lists the users names (`-printf '%u\n'` option) in the working directory. `-maxdepth 1` prevents searching sub-directories. `-not -name '.*'` excludes dot files. `sort | uniq` has the same purpose as in the original example.

Comment: I don't think the sed is working as it is supposed to. it is replacing 's' with space

Comment: @ErwinSmith You may replace the `sed` with `tr -s ' '`.